# AngularJS - Basic $index with ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have two tables with tr like this, only changing the holderId

```
 <tr class="text-center" ng-if="obligation3.debtor.holderId == 3"
     ng-repeat="obligation in vm.application.obligations">
   <td><b>Ratenkredit&nbsp;{{$index+1}}&nbsp;</b></td>
</tr>

 <tr class="text-center" ng-if="obligation.debtor.holderId == 2"
     ng-repeat="obligation in vm.application.obligations">
   <td><b>Ratenkredit&nbsp;{{$index+1}}&nbsp;</b></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the `$index` does not reset. I want to count the number of `$index` in the for loop and in the second loop `$index` should start as 0:

[image: Check this image]

Secondary Applicant table should start at 1.

Comment: $index DO reset, your problem might be that $index ignores your ng-if clause?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I think that's the problem. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-if`, use a filter.

```
<tr class="text-center" 
    ng-repeat="obligation in vm.application.obligations | filter: { debtor.holderId: 3 }: true">

<tr class="text-center" 
    ng-repeat="obligation in vm.application.obligations | filter: { debtor.holderId: 2 }: true">
```

The `true` tells the filter to use strict matching, otherwise it would match items where `holderId` is 13, 23, etc.